# update Mongoose document without Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to update an mongoose object directly without using its model?

I tried this code:

```
var user = new User();
//setting some user properties
//...
user.save(); //works
```

in a seperate call i do:

```
user.update(function(error, result){
  //the update doesn't happend, but no error
  //result = [ok=1,nModified=0,n=1]
});
```

so this approach doesn't throw an Exception and there is no error. But it also doesn't work.

When I ask google for ways to update a document with mongoose
I always find approaches like

```
UserModel.update({ /*selector*/ }, {$set: { /**/ }}, function(error, result){/*...*/});
```

I can save my example "user"-object with this approach. So that works.

But I want to know if my approach to save to document/object directly is also supported? So am I doing something wrong? Or is this way of updating a document  not supported by mongoose?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not updating anything in the

```
user.update(function(error, result){
 //the update doesn't happend, but no error
 //result = [ok=1,nModified=0,n=1]
});
```

That's why it seems to you that it is not working. What happens is you're supplying and `undefined` selector and an `undefined` update (`$set`).

Try `user.update({}, {$set:{ ... }}function(error, result){ ... }`.

Comment: Why was my answer down voted? Please give me some explanation.